# Neo4j cypher query for getting the number of relationships to a node, for each distinct label

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have the following circumstance:

Two types of nodes; `NodeA` and `NodeB`. `NodeB` has numerous different labels (lets, say `[LABEL_i, LABEL_j, etc...]`), and I want to find the number of relationships (let's say `LIKES`) from `NodeA` to `NodeB` for **each** label on `NodeB`.

For a single label, I can do the following:

```
MATCH (a:NodeA {uid: "<id>"})-[r:LIKES]-(b:NodeB:LABEL_i) RETURN count(b) as count
```

For which i get back the number of relationships to `NodeB` with the label `LABEL_i`.

I should be able to combine the above logic into a single query to Neo4j, but I can't get it to work, I've tried the following approaches (just fields on the response):

```
MATCH (a:NodeA {uid: "<id>"})-[r:LIKES]-(b:NodeB) RETURN DISTINCT LABELS(b), count(b), SIZE(LABLES(b))
```

But the data I got back from that was not what I was expecting or need, nor can I find other approaches that work, the following are what I tried too

```
FOREACH (lab in ["LABEL_i", "LABEL_j"] | 
  MATCH (a:NodeA {uid: "<id>"})-[r:LIKES]-(b:lab) RETURN count(b) as count
)
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid use of MATCH inside FOREACH (line 2, column 3 (offset: 49))
```

Any help in how to write this query would be much appreciated, I only recently started using Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a case of either when writing up a question here, that you find the answer, or a little while after of posting, you stumble upon the correct solution.

The following is what I used to accomplish the problem:

```
MATCH (a:NodeA {uid: "<id>"})-[r:LIKES]-(b:NodeB)
WITH DISTINCT labels(b) AS labels
UNWIND labels AS label
RETURN DISTINCT label, count(label)
ORDER BY label
```